# KornShell getting latest file versions

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to write a KornShell (ksh) script to get the latest three versions for a file in the directory having lot of files with various versions (files with prefix as same but time stamp as suffix) and compress it and at the same time have to remove the remaining versions of the file (other than latest three versions of the file). 
I'm new to KornShell scripting. Can any one provide me with solution?
The directory structure is like this:

```
abcd.11122013.txt
abcd.12122013.txt
abcd.10122013.txt
abcd.09122013.txt
xyz.11122013.txt
xyz.12122013.txt
xyz.10122013.txt
......................
```

In this I want the latest 3 version of files starting with abcd* as prefix. Similarly files starting with xyz*.

Answer (score 0):

There are undoubtedly simpler ones but here is one way:

```
for base in abcd xyz
do
    ls ${base}* | sed 's/\(.*\).\(..\)\(..\)\(....\).txt/\4 \3 \2 \1/' | sort | tail -3 | while read a b c d;do echo $d.$c$b$a.txt; done
done
```

Update: using an array to store the prefixes and showing one way to call the archive function for each file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -a prefix=(abcd xyz foo bar)
for base in "${prefix[@]}"
do
  for file in $(ls "${base}"* | 
                sed 's/\(.*\).\(..\)\(..\)\(....\).txt/\4 \3 \2 \1/' |
                sort |
                tail -3 |
                while read a b c d; do
                  echo $d.$c$b$a.txt
                done); do
    echo archive $file
  done
done
```

Comment: You can replace the `ls` call by a better one : `echo` or `printf`.

Comment: @sputnick I might replace it indeed but that would require a little bit more code to handle the case where no file starting with `$base` exist. `ls` is already pretty good at doing it and is reporting an appropriate error message.

Comment: I disagree, you can use `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: @sputnick That's a bashism while the question is about ksh. In any case, that wouldn't display an error message should no file exist so would be less convenient imho.

Comment: can i get any approach like keeping the required set of prefix files in array and looping in korn shell. because I have different set of files with different prefixes. i want to get the latest 3 files per prefix and archive those.

Comment: I was already processing multiple prefixes. Answer updated anyway using a ksh array this time.

Comment: Hi for my above question, I am compressing the latest 3 versions of a prefix and at the same time I have to remove the remaining versions of the prefix . how can I achieve that.

Comment: @jilliagre Hi for my above question, I am compressing the latest 3 versions of a prefix and at the same time I have to remove the remaining versions of the prefix . how can I achieve that. –

Answer (score 0):

One way using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
printf '%s\n' * |
    perl -F'\'. -lane '
        /^abcd/ and
            $h{
                substr($F[1], 4, 4),
                substr($F[1], 2, 2),
                substr($F[1], 0, 2)
            } = $_;
        END{
             $c=0;
             for (sort $a <=> $b, keys %h) {
                  print $h{$_};
                  $c++ == 3 and last;
             }
        }
    '
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file modification times are correct, it could be as simple as:

```
ls -tr abcd* | tail -3
```